# How do I show the user a certain text only when he/she is within a specified location or radius?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-location

I am developing an app and what I want is I want the user to see a particular text only when she/he is in the specified location or radius. 
Like if the user is within 2kms of a given area/coordinates, he/she would be able to see a particular text otherwise the text would disappear.

As I don't know how to do this, I have no code yet. Sorry!

Please cooperate with the bad question format, I'm still learning to post good questions.

Comment: do you know basics of google maps api and places api. if you dont then i suggest please do that first, it will be easier for you.

Comment: @SagarNayak how/where should I know about it?

Comment: maps api - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/

   places api- https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/

Answer (score 0):

You can make a service that checks every given time if the location of the device its <2km of the location you have marked, and then show the TextView.

Comment: many thanks for responding. Can you please provide me some code? Please! I'm a beginner still!

Comment: This solution requires some code. Learn about Android Services. And then, get the distance. Its not that hard, believe me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`LocationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) after registering with [`requestLocationUpdates`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29).

Inside your `LocationListener`'s `onLocationChanged` method, you can perform the neccessary actions depending on the user's location.

Comment: hey! can you tell me about some tutorial or can you give more precise code? Please?

Comment: Just google "Android maps api" and you will find tons of tutorials.